# Changing display of elements in hover of another element does not work as it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I want to change the display of the elements with the .slide-prev and .slide-next classes. As I'm using a slide plugin, it automatically creates the navigation elements outside the ul, so the only way the display change worked was with javascript. The problem is that it did not work as it should.

When I move the mouse over the div with the class .intro-noticias the elements appear, and when I leave they disappear, so far so good. The problem is when I hover over the elements .slide-prev and .slide-next, they are shaking, disappearing depending on where the arrow is and do not activate the hover.

It may be that I let something simple go by, but I really have not found it, if anyone knows what's causing it, I appreciate it.

[Video demonstrating the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsFqgij0RWE&feature=youtu.be)

```js
$(".intro-noticias").hover(function() {
    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "block");
}, function() {
    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
.intro-noticias {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.slide-prev {
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}

.slide-prev:after {
  content:"icon";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9.5px;
  left: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: url("img/icones/previous.png") left center no-repeat;
}

.slide-prev:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.slide-next {
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 40px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}

.slide-next:after {
  content:"icon";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9.5px;
  right: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: url("img/icones/next.png") right center no-repeat;
}

.slide-next:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <div class="intro-noticias"> 
          <div>
              <h2></h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="slide-prev">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="slide-next">Next</a>
```

Comment: we need a [mcve], otherwise we're just taking guesses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap ul and anchors into the `<div class="cont">` and bind events mouseenter and mouseleave to this div.

```html
<div class="cont">
 <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="intro-noticias">  
          <div>
              <h2></h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" class="slide-prev">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="slide-next">Next</a>
</div>
```

```javascript
$(".cont").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "block");
});
$(".cont").mouseleave(function() {
    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that way unfortunately the result is the same

Comment: I've changed the answer. have a look.

Comment: Is not possible, the slide plugin puts the navigation out of any element

Comment: Actually worked, I thought the anchors would stay out of the div, but no. thank you